# Multiple deep watch: duplicate key

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a weirdo syntax problem with declaring `deep:true` watchers on vuejs:

This is working fine, both watchers triggers when expected and so one:

```js
    watch: {
      'focus': function () {
        this.visible = this.focus.map(bool => bool)
      },deep:true,
      'map': function (newval, oldval) {
        Vue.set(this.nmap, oldval, !this.nmap[oldval])
        Vue.set(this.nmap, newval, !this.nmap[newval])
      },
    },
```

but if I try to add a new watcher with `deep: true` properties it outputs an error that says: `Duplicate key 'deep'`

```js
    watch: {
      'focus': function () {
        this.visible = this.focus.map(bool => bool)
      },deep:true,
      'map': function (newval, oldval) {
        Vue.set(this.nmap, oldval, !this.nmap[oldval])
        Vue.set(this.nmap, newval, !this.nmap[newval])
      },
      'selected': function (newval, oldval) {
        console.log('Old val:')
        console.log(oldval)
        console.log('New val:')
        console.log(newval)
      },deep:true,
    },
```

How I'm supposed to declare this new watcher over this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what you tell us, I assume that focus, map, and selected are data objects that might get changed. The following code would execute the function in handler once there is a change:

```js
watch: {
    focus: {
        handler: function() {
            this.visible = this.focus.map(bool => bool)
        }, deep: true
    },
    map: function(newval, oldval) {
        Vue.set(this.nmap, oldval, !this.nmap[oldval])
        Vue.set(this.nmap, newval, !this.nmap[newval])
    },
    selected: {
        handler: function(newval, oldval) {
            console.log('Old val:')
            console.log(oldval)
            console.log('New val:')
            console.log(newval)
        }, deep: true,
    }
}
```

Source: [VueJS Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)